# Sorting a map by it's element in value which is pair using C++

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, key-value, custom-compare

How do I write custom sorting for map with such attributes --

```
map <int, pair<int,int> > Valuedensity
```

I want to sort with

```
sort(Valuedensity.begin(),Valuedensity.end(),myfn(int, pair<int,int>))
```

But I do not how to define this myfn() such that it sorts the map using second element in value pair of map ( `el.second.second` ).

Comment: If you mean `std::map`, it is sorted. You can't re-sort it.

Comment: I want to sort it by second element in value pair, Isn't that possible ?

Comment: It is not possible to sort it by anything. It is already sorted, by the key.

Comment: I am looking for something similar to the way in python                                                               d = OrderedDict(sorted(visited.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))